# Flutter - initState expecting return value of Future<String>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the code working before but after introduction of null safety, this below code is breaking with the error

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future<String?>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

Below is the code and am not sure, what needs to be changed

```
@override
  void initState() {
    SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) {
      // debugPrint('SystemChannels> $msg');
      super.initState();

      if (msg == AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString()) {
        // print("in resumed of payments");
        setState(() {
          dataLoaded = false;
        });
        customerPayments();
      } else {
        throw Exception("In Else");
      }
    });
  }
```

`customerPayments()` is a void method.

Comment: This is not likely the only problem, but your super.initState belongs as the very first line of initState.  This is stated as required in the API docs.

Comment: The error does not cause by the initState method. It is caused by the setMessageHandler method because its parameter is a callback of type Future<String?>. When we pass the callback as its parameter, we must return a Future<String?> inside the setMessageHandler method.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a function inside your `initState` and that function requires a return value for every possible outcome. However, among other issues, you shouldn't be calling `super.initState()` inside the function you declared in there. You can call it before or after depending on what you're doing.

Essentially with that particular error message it's basically saying that as far as Flutter can tell, there is a chance that the function might end without a potential return value resulting in it returning null.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

```
@override
void initState() {
  SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) {
    // debugPrint('SystemChannels> $msg');
    super.initState();

    if (msg == AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString()) {
      // print("in resumed of payments");
      setState(() {
        dataLoaded = false;
      });
      customerPayments();
    } else {
      throw Exception("In Else");
    }
    //Return statement would go here.
  });
}
```

Comment: i might be completely missing the point here but what I fail to understand here is why should a void function return a value?